# how do you recreate an table structure and table data that is on oracle database A to oracle database B?

Tags: oracle-11g

I have an Oracle 11g database with about 10 tables filled with data on a database server A.

I want to recreate everything (table structure and all data inside each of the 10 tables) on a database server B.

Server A and server B don't talk to each other and are completely different machines.

I have heard of something called "database dump". I've also heard of import and export.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: "Easy" will depend on things like data volume, privileges, your downtime window, etc.  My guess is that the database is small enough and your downtime window is large enough that a simple export and import would be the simplest option.  But that wouldn't be the easiest option if one of your table is a TB in size and you only have a couple minutes of downtime.

Comment: @JustinCave - the database is probably 1 or 2 GB at most. If you answer the questions with the exact export/import commands I will mark it correct. thanks.

Comment: The exact parameters will depend on exactly what you want to do.  My guess would be that you want a schema level export but you might want a full export.  The old `exp` and `imp` utilities are depricated but they'll still work in 11g and might be easier to work with when you have a database this small and a generous downtime window.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm

Comment: @JustinCave - one more question (and if you answer this I can mark it correct): i'm not 100% sure if there are exactly 10 tables. There might be 11 or 12 tables.  Is the export functionality in oracle 11g smart enough to "figure out" what the other missing tables are and grab them too?

Comment: If you do a schema-level export, every table in the schema will be exported (unless you use the DataPump version of the utility and specifically exclude them).  If you do a table-level export, you would need to explicitly list the objects you want exported.  I'm not sure what you mean here by "missing"